# Android Service vs Background thread over Application.onCreate()

Tags: android, background-process

After carefully reading Android docs regarding choosing to invoke a long-running work on top of a [Service or a Thread](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services#Choosing-service-thread), I haven't found a deterministic answer to the following:

On the Application.OnCreate() callback it is possible to invoke some Thread and launch a long-running task, as long as the application is alive it will work. If the user exit the Activity, these task would still be active as long as the OS doesn't kill the application.

I also know that Android has a policy to always uses as much RAM as possible, i.e keep apps active and not to eliminate them.

So I actually started to think, why should I use a Service at all, what is the true benefit of it ?(beside using a foreground service with a persisted notification)

The only answer I can give is that once the OS has no memory available it starts killing processes, and due to not having a service it will priorities my app as less important, thus more chances to be the first one to get killed.

Is there an official recommended approach for it?

Also, assuming the application has 25 different business logics which are long-running background tasks, the logics have no relation to each other. Therefore, assuming we wish to use Android's services should we invoke 25 different services?

Comment: "I also know that Android has a policy to always uses as much RAM as possible, i.e keep apps active and not to eliminate them." - this is based on what, exactly?

Comment: That background thread has no guarantee to be executed when the app is in background. Just read the docs https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks